# Use ADB to clear specific cookies from an android device?

Tags: android, adb

I am writing UI tests for our android app, and authentication is handled via a webview (and then redirectes back to the app when done).  I am clearing app data between tests, but I also need to find a way to delete the specific cookies from Chrome before the next test, or else is will automatically authenticate again.  I know I can clear all data from chrome using `adb shell pm clear com.android.chrome`, but this will also reset Chrome and force me to Accept the TOS and then tell Chrome I don't want to sign back in.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the standard Google Chrome, then I don't think you can do that. I would install a debuggable browser, to which I have full access via `adb shell run-as <browser's package id>`. I suspect the cookies to be stored in cache. So, maybe `rm -rf /data/data/<browser's package id>/cache/*` would work. Otherwise, you'd have to dig in `/data/data/<browser's package id>` and try to find where the cookies are stored.

Comment: What browser would you recommend?

Comment: @kroe761 There is a list of open-source browsers here https://github.com/topics/android-browser that you can choose from, compile on your own with a debug key, and use as a debuggable app.